# Coset proofs for Binary Code

Tags: coding-theory

Can someone please help with the following proof:

C is a binary [n, k, d]-code.

Suppose d ≥ 2t + 1. Show that every word of weight ≤ t is a coset leader in
every Slepian array for C.

So i know n = length, k = dimension and d = distance and the slepian array is a way of displaying the cosets of C

I have tried taking the approach that we know the number of cosets is q^(n-k)
and therefore i tried to use that knowledge to form a proof, as choosing cosets is based on minimum weight however I didnt get very far

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nearly always the number of words of weight $\le t$ is much lower than $q^{n-k}$. The exceptions are so called perfect codes, and they are very few, indeed, single-error correcting Hamming codes (and those with equivalent distance distribution, any field alphabet) and the Golay codes (binary and ternary).

Comment: But here's what you should try. Let $x$ be a word of weight $\le t$. Let $y$ be any other word in the coset $x+C$. Because $x-y$ is a non-zero codeword, can you show that the weight of $y$ is at least $t+1$?

Comment: To be honest i am a little confused still sorry...proofs are a real weak point for me